# Android Sqlite insert null object reference

Tags: android, sqlite, insert

I'm taking an intro to android programming course running into some issues adding to the sqlite database

Any suggestions what might be causing this error. I think it is related to not having the proper assignment to the mDatabase field variable.

It seems like the issue is that mDatabase variable in the addCustomer function needs different context.

```
  private static ContentValues getContentValues(Customer customer) { 
     ContentValues values = new ContentValues(); 
     values.put(UUID, customer.getId().toString()); 
     values.put(FULL_NAME, customer.getName()); 
     values.put(ADDRESS, customer.getAddress()); 
     values.put(CREDIT_CARD_NUMBER, customer.getCreditCardNumber()); 
     values.put(EMAIL, customer.getEmail()); 
     values.put(SESSIONS_REMAINING, customer.getSessionsRemaining()); 
     values.put(PRINT_RECEIPT, customer.getPrintReceipt() ? 1 : 0); 
     values.put(EMAIL_RECEIPT, customer.getEmailReceipt() ? 1 : 0); 
     return values; 
 } 

 public void addCustomer(Customer c) { 
    ContentValues values = getContentValues(c); 
    mDatabase.insert(CustomerDbSchema.CustomerTable.NAME, null, values); 
    Log.d("DATABASE", "Customer Added"); 
 }
```

File Links on Github below:

[CustomerDataBase.java](https://github.com/zcbuhler/FitnessTracker/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/z/buhler/fitnesstracker/database/CustomerBaseHelper.java)

[CustomerCursorWrapper.java](https://github.com/zcbuhler/FitnessTracker/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/z/buhler/fitnesstracker/database/CustomerCursorWrapper.java)

[CustomerDBSchema.java](https://github.com/zcbuhler/FitnessTracker/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/z/buhler/fitnesstracker/database/CustomerDbSchema.java)

[Customer.java](https://github.com/zcbuhler/FitnessTracker/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/z/buhler/fitnesstracker/Customer.java)

[AddCustomerActivity.java](https://github.com/zcbuhler/FitnessTracker/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/z/buhler/fitnesstracker/AddCustomerActivity.java)

Comment: post the log errors

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.content.ContentValues)' on a null object reference

Answer (score 0):

1) I think you are not using the `SQLiteDatabase mDatabase = getWritableDatabase();` properly.
2) See the [ContentValues](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentValues.html) for more info.
3) Use an `if` to make sure it was inserted.

```
    if (mDatabase.insert(CustomerDbSchema.CustomerTable.NAME, null, contentValues) > 0) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
```